# How to perform F-test in R for checking equality-of-variance (homoscedasticity/heteroscedasticity) if raw data is not given?

Tags: r, variance, heteroscedasticity, two-sample

In a typical two-sample problem scenario, I possess the sample mean, variance, and size, but not the raw data for samples drawn from two populations. I wish to perform the F-test to check equality of variance (homoscedasticity). In R, the built-in function `var.test` allows me to perform the F-test if I have the sample data in vector format, however, I don't have the raw data.

---

I found this library ([BSDA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BSDA/BSDA.pdf)) to perform the pooled t-test if raw data was not given.

How should I perform the F-test? Is there a library similar to BSDA for performing the F-test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With data.** First, it is important to know how the `var.test` in R works, if you *do* have the (normal) data.
Consider data as follows:

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = rnorm(20, 19, 5);  x2 = rnorm(30, 10, 8)

stripchart(list(x1,x2), pch="|", ylim=c(.5,2.5))
```

[image]

With respective sample variances $S_1^2, S_2^2.$
The test statistic for testing
$H_0: \sigma_1^2/\sigma_2^2 = 1$ against
$H_a: \sigma_1^2/\sigma_2^2 < 1$ is $F = S_1^2/S_2^2.$ Under $H_0,$ $F \sim\mathsf{R}(\nu_1=19, \nu_2=29).$

```
var.test(x1, x2, alt="less")

        F test to compare two variances

data:  x1 and x2
F = 0.37735, num df = 19, denom df = 29, 
 p-value = 0.01503

alternative hypothesis: 
 true ratio of variances is less than 1

95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0000000 0.7838272
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.3773455
```

The F-statistic is $S_1^2/S_2^2 = 0.3773.$

```
var(x1)/var(x2)
[1] 0.3773455
```

The P-value is $P(F \le 0.3773) = 0.015.$

```
pf(0.3773, 19, 29)
[1] 0.01501539
```

In the figure below the P-value for this one-sided test is the area under the density curve to the
left of the vertical black line.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
curve(df(x, 19,29), 0, 4, lwd=2, col="blue", 
     ylab="Density", xlab="f", main="PDF of F(19, 29)")
abline(v =  0.3773, lwd=2)
abline(v = 0, col="green2")
abline(h = 0, col="green2")
```

*Note:* For a two-sided test, the P-value is doubled:

```
var.test(x1,x2)$p.val
[1] 0.03005009
```

**With sample variances and sample sizes:** Then with this background, it is easy to use R to do
a one-sided F test for equal variances if you know only the two variances and sample sizes. Just
use the PDF of the distribution $\mathsf{F}(19,20)$ to find the P-value $0.0150:$

```
v1 = var(x1);  v2 = var(x2);  f = v1/v2
v1; v2; f
[1] 29.63551
[1] 78.53681
[1] 0.3773455
pf(f, 19, 29)
[1] 0.01502505
```

For a right-sided test the P-value is computed
in the right tail of the F distribution. Here
are examples with data and with sample variances:

```
set.seed(1126)
y1 = rnorm(25, 30, 10)
y2 = rnorm(20, 45, 5)
var.test(y1, y2, alt="gr")$p.val
[1] 7.786383e-05
1 - pf(var(y1)/var(y2), 24, 19)
[1] 7.786383e-05
```

Comment: Thanks @BruceET for the answer. However, in cases when the F-statistic is smaller than 1, the p-value is computed to be $2*p[F_{n_2-1;n_1-1}> 1/F_{obs}]$ for the 2-sided test.

Comment: Not necessary. That identity is necessary only if you're using printed tables of the F distribution that give only upper tail quantiles (to save space in print). Software programs such as R will give lower tail probabilities and quantiles directly. // You mentioned R in your question, so I assumed you're using R.